# Is $(c_{00}, \|.\|_\infty)$ not a Banach space?

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, normed-spaces, solution-verification

Is $(c_{00}, \|.\|_\infty)$ is not a Banach space?

if $c_{00} = \{x = (x_1, x_2, . . .) : x_n = 0$ for all but finitely many $n\}$ with $\|.\|_\infty$.

If I let the following sequence $v_n = (1,\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{4},\dots,\frac{1}{2^n},0,0,\dots)$, then $v_n\in l^\infty$ and  $v_n\in c_{00} $. So we have that $v_n \to v$ where ;

\begin{align}
& v_n = (1,\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{4},\dots,\frac{1}{2^n},0,0,\dots) \\
& v = (1,\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{4},\dots,\frac{1}{2^n},\frac{1}{2^{n+1}},\dots) \ \ \ \ \text{(no zeros)} ,  \ \ \ \ \sup|\frac{1}{2^n}|<\infty \implies v\in l^\infty\\
\end{align}

Hence,  $v\in l^\infty$ but $v\notin c_{00} $ as we can see above. So $c_{00} $ is not a closed subset of $l^\infty$, thus it is incomplete.

Comment: Why does $v_n\to v$ imply that $v_n\not\to x$ for any $x\in c_{00}$?

Comment: that is my end conclusion, I should have written that better. Will edit.

Comment: What is written is correct, complete spaces are always closed when included into a bigger metric space.